# How to fix "No available formula" warning for Homebrew

Tags: php, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

When I start a new terminal session, I keep getting

```
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php56"
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap homebrew/php
```

warning. I tried `brew tap homebrew/php` but got

```
Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
```

Also, tried `brew doctor`, `brew cleanup`, `brew update` & `brew upgrade` but no luck. Does anyone have a solution to this annoying warning?

Comment: It was deprecated. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php

Comment: @haidang I am aware of that. My problem is, I can't get rid of the depreciation warning even with `brew cleanup`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look in the configuration file for your shell (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, or similar) and remove the offending items.

In my case I still had a reference to it in my `export PATH` line. Removing `$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bin` from that line should clear those warnings on startup.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with

```
$ brew install php72
```